# Stop onmouseenter repeatedly firing in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm having a nightmare trying to figure this out. The onmouseenter even keeps firing ever after the mouse enters a div with the event, every time the mouse moves it triggers the funciton. It works fine in IE, just not Chrome or FF. Here is a live version of code : http://infinitedv.co.uk/rantest/random_test_2.1.html

I've not preloaded the images, so it may take a few passes to see all the images. Thank you in advance for any help. I've tried using a timeout, but that didn't really pan out, and was messy.

```js
var ranNum, result_10, resultFloor, piccy, audio, a, divVar;

function myFunction(a) {
 if (a === 0) {
  divVar = "demo";
 }
 else if (a === 1) {
  divVar = "demo1";
 }
 else if (a === 2) {
  divVar = "demo2";
 }
 ranNum = Math.random();
 result_10 = (ranNum * 5) + 1;
 resultFloor = Math.floor(result_10);
 piccy = "<img src=\"random_images/" + resultFloor + ".gif\" />";
 document.getElementById(divVar).innerHTML = piccy;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="demo" onmouseenter="myFunction(0)">This</div>
    <div id="demo1" onmouseenter="myFunction(1)">This</div>
    <div id="demo2" onmouseenter="myFunction(2)">This</div>
    <div>Will's Imagepop test. </div>
    <audio id="audio" src="pop.wav" ></audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, really weird. But it is something with the `innerHTML` of the div. Check this version where it is working with the background image instead of replacing its content.

```js
var ranNum, result_10, resultFloor, piccy, audio, a, divVar;

function myFunction(a) {
    console.log('function called for', a);
 if (a === 0) {
  divVar = "demo";
 }
 else if (a === 1) {
  divVar = "demo1";
 }
 else if (a === 2) {
  divVar = "demo2";
 }
 ranNum = Math.random();
 result_10 = (ranNum * 5) + 1;
 resultFloor = Math.floor(result_10);
 piccy = "<img src=\"random_images/" + resultFloor + ".gif\" />";
 //document.getElementById(divVar).innerHTML = piccy;
        document.getElementById(divVar).style.background = "url(random_images/" + resultFloor + ".gif)";
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="demo" onmouseenter="myFunction(0)">This</div>
    <div id="demo1" onmouseenter="myFunction(1)">This</div>
    <div id="demo2" onmouseenter="myFunction(2)">This</div>
    <div>Will's Imagepop test. </div>
    <audio id="audio" src="pop.wav" ></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked brilliantly, thank you. It's also a lot more responsive to the event. It must be something to do with the way chrome and FF redraw divs using innerHTML. Thank you, thank you. :)

Comment: @Cuckoo yes, probably is something with the rerender / redraw. But it is really weird.